# Crashlytics - Testers not receiving invitation email

Tags: crashlytics, twitter-fabric, google-fabric, crashlytics-beta

Every now and then, we have problems with testers not receiving the invite at all.

As we use Fabric to sent the mobile apps for our clients, this has become a huge issue. We have figured out that some email domains simply don't receive the invitation, like our own company domain (and there's no filter on our end blocking the invitation).

But currently there is a issue with a client not receiving an invite, even though it's a hotmail address.

Why is this happening and how can we send those invitations properly? We really like using Fabric whole suit, so we don't want to simply search for a different Beta service.

Comment: Mike from Fabric here. I'd recommend emailing support(at)fabric(dot)io with a list of testers email addresses that aren't getting invites. There's two likely situations, one is that a tester was previously invited and isn't getting notifications of new builds or that a mail server on our end or the company's side is having an issue.

Comment: Thanks @mike, we will do that.